# Keep Smart Scopes settings set

Tags: unity, search, lenses

I recently upgraded to 13.10 Saucy Salamander and as most of us know, it is the first Ubuntu version to truly use Smart Scopes. While this is useful and I do like *parts* of it, I don't want all of the results it brings.

So, I went over to the Filter Results bar and changed it to what I wanted (it was giving me online results over searching my computer and such, such not even bringing up Firefox when I searched for it) and then started the program I wanted.

Later I went back to search and all of those specifications I made were gone. It was bringing up online results first again and all of the defaults I had turned off were back on.

Here's a screenshot of what is happening:
[image: firefox search]

I don't completely want to remove Scopes, as I have heard this can cause problems, but I really would like the functionality I need.

Also, when I go to, say the Applications Scope, it just shows this:

[image: application scope]

I can't browse my applications!

Please help me, as I really don't want to remove Scopes or even down-grade to 13.04!

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: @FrankSlezak Sorry, I had to go get my braces taken off *Hallelujah!Hallelujah!* Yes, marking as answer

Comment: Glad i could help. WOAH. 777 reputation....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing `unity-lens-applications`

You can do this by `sudo apt-get install unity-lens-applications`

If that doesn't work, remove it with `sudo apt-get purge unity-lens-applications` 
**MAKE SURE IT WON'T REMOVE ANY OTHER PACKAGES!** If it does, make a note of them.

Then, `sudo apt-get install unity-lens-applications <+ any purged>`

Also, try `sudo apt-get install unity-scope-home`

If that doesn't work, try `rm -rf ~/.local/share/zeitgeist` and relogging.

Comment: This worked when I ran `sudo apt-get purge unity-lens-applications` and then `sudo apt-get install unity-lens-applications`. This didn't seem to work, so I also tried `sudo apt-get purge unity-scope-home` and then `sudo apt-get install unity-scope-home`, as per this answer. I then logged out and back in again and it works perfectly! The good old purge-reinstall-logout-login approach works again.

Comment: Okay...just rebooted and the issue is back :P

Comment: ehrm... it appears to be a config. Try `rm -rf ~/.local/share/zeitgeist`

Comment: Do I need to logout and back in again for it to take effect, because just running the command has no effect.. :(

Comment: read the answer...

Comment: *facepalm*...wow

Comment: glad its working for you.

Comment: Okay. What the world is going on? Its back again. I guess this is going to be one of those problems that is totally random and I will just have to put up with it.

Comment: sadly, i have no idea anymore... sorry. EDIT: maybe there's some package breaking Zeitgeist. You can try purging/reinstalling Unity. look that up at google.